# Qt QLCDNumber Timer

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I have made a timer using QLCDNumber to be displayed on my status bar. I have tried to connect to my slot. However, it seems like the slot never ever get called. Can anyone advise me on what has gone wrong?

Thanks.

By the way, if I were to use this approach, will the timer be counting up according to how a clock time is ticking? (i.e. when the seconds reach 59, it will reset to 0, and minutes will turn 1.)

My .h:

```
class StatusBar : public QStatusBar, QLCDNumber
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StatusBar()
    {
        m_simulation = 0;
        createButtons();
    };
    ~StatusBar() { };

public slots:
    void countUp();

private:
    QLCDNumber *lcdSimulation;
    int m_simulation;
    QTimer *simulationTimer;
};
```

My .cpp:

```
void StatusBar::createButtons()
{
    ...

    lcdSimulation = new QLCDNumber;
    lcdSimulation->setNumDigits(8);
    lcdSimulation->display("12:00:00");
    simulationTimer = new QTimer;
    simulationTimer->start(5000);
    QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), lcdSimulation, SLOT(countUp()));
    addWidget(lcdSimulation);

    ...
}

void StatusBar::countUp()
{
    m_simulation++;
    lcdSimulation->display(m_simulation);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in incorrect target object for the signal.

Wrong

```
QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), lcdSimulation, SLOT(countUp()));
```

Correct

```
QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(countUp()));
```

Because your `countUp()` defined in `StatusBar` class and not in `QLCDNumber`.

Comment: I changed to the correct statement but it returns me an `error C2594 'argument' : ambigous conversions from StatusBar* const to const Object*`. I am thinking that something has went wrong with the connect statement but I just don't know why it isn't called.

Comment: that's because you use diamond derivation : you derivate from QStatusBar and QLcdNumber, both of them derivates from QObject. Hence, the ambiguity

Comment: I see. In this situation, how and which should I inherit from? My lcdSimulation is sitting on the status bar. Thus, the need for me to inherit from QStatusBar and QLCDNumber. Or is there a workaround?

Comment: @Wallace, I think you don't need to inherit `QLCDNumber` - you already have `QLCDNumber` as a member variable.

Comment: @vahancho: Thanks! I removed QLCDNumber and only inherited from QStatusBar. However, there's one other problem. I wanted to let it count like a clock timer (i.e. 12:00:00, 12:00:01, 12:00:02...). But in this case, it resets to 0, 1, 2, 3...

Comment: @Wallace, it shows 1, 2... because you feed the integer values to it in your slot. What you need is keep track on the time and use something like `QTime::toString()` function to display.

Comment: @vahancho: Thanks. I did something like the following. It returns me the `currentTime()` which works. How do I make it count from the time that I stated? (i.e. 12:00:00).

`void StatusBar::countUp()
{
    QTime time = QTime::currentTime();
    QString text = time.toString("hh:mm:ss");
    if((time.second() % 2) == 0)
        text[2] = ' ';
    lcdSimulation->display(text);
};`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say like that but I would check that :

- your header file is correctly moc-ed (check that a moc_statusbar.cpp is generated, compiled and linked)
- your StatusBar class composes (*lcdSimulation) and derivates from QLCDNumber : you should choose which one is the best (composition most probably)
- connect returns a boolean : you should assert on this. If asserts fails, check console to know what happened (a trace is emitted on mismatch)
- in your case, the slot is defined in `this`, not `lcdNumber`

Reworked code:

```
bool b=QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(countUp()));
Q_ASSERT(b);
```

Comment: 1) Yes, the header file is correctly moc-ed.
2) My StatusBar class is derived from QLCDNumber and lcdSimulation is declared as a private member.
3) I tried the assert method, which returns me an `error C4189 : 'b' local variable is initialized but not referenced.` However, I already included `Q_ASSERT(b);`

Comment: I defined as `this`. However, it returns me the `error C2594 'argument' : ambigous conversions from StatusBar* const to const Object*`, which I understand that it is derivating from both QStatusBar and QLCDNumber.